# How do I get my train() function to operate in shiny to evaluate model performance?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a project to create a shiny app that allows users to do some modeling, choose a model and make some predictions.

When I run the train() function in the r console on my data it works fine.  When I run it in my shiny app, I consistently get an error: contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels.  My dataframe has no factors.  Can't figure out why it works in console but not shiny.  Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Variables Impacting Hate Crime Rates"),

    # define main panel layout
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                        tabPanel("Information",
                                 textOutput("introduction")),
                        tabPanel("Data Exploration",
                                 textOutput("data"),
                                 selectInput("x","Explanatory variable:",
                                             choices = colnames(crimes),
                                             selected = "median_household_income"),
                                 selectInput("y","Response variable:",
                                             selected = "median_household_income",
                                            choices = colnames(crimes)),
                                 plotOutput("scatterplot"),
                                 selectInput("y2", "Variable to compare:",
                                             selected = "median_household_income",
                                             choices = colnames(crimes)),
                                 plotOutput("boxplot"),
                                 selectInput("var","Summary variable:",
                                             choices = colnames(crimes),
                                             selected = "median_household_income"),
                                 verbatimTextOutput("summary"))
                        ,
                        tabPanel("Unsupervised Learning",
                                 selectInput("k","Number of clusters:",
                                             choices = c(1,2,3),
                                             selected = 1),
                                 plotOutput("cluster"),
                                 selectInput("dmethod","Distance method:",
                                             choices = c("euclidian","binary","minkowski",
                                                         "canberra","manhattan","maximum"),
                                             selected = "euclidian"),
                                 selectInput("cmethod", "Cluster method:",
                                             choices = c("single","complete"),
                                             selected = "single"),
                                 plotOutput("tree")),
                        tabPanel("Modeling",
                                 selectInput("xvar", "x variable:",
                                            choices = colnames(crimes),
                                            selected = "gini_index"),
                                 selectInput("yvar", "y variable:",
                                             choices = colnames(crimes),
                                             selected = "median_household_income"),
                                 verbatimTextOutput("model")),
                        tabPanel("Data",
                                 DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
        )
    )
))


source("C:/Users/W447075/Documents/ST558/Comora_final/helpers.R")

shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
     output$introduction <- renderText({
        "This is my introduction"
    })

     output$data <- renderText({
       "This page allows you to create some basic graphical
       and numeric summaries including a scatter plot, boxplot,
       and statistical summary for any of the variables in the 
       'crimes' dataset."
     })

    selectedData <- reactive({
      crimes %>% filter(region ==input$region)
    })
    selectData2 <- reactive({
      crimes[ , c("region",input$y)]
    })

    selectData3 <- reactive({
      crimes[ , c("region", input$y2)]
    })

    mydata <- reactive({
      crimes[ ,input$var]
    })

    mycluster <- reactive({
      kmeans(df_scale, centers = input$k, nstart = 25)
    })

    d <- reactive({
      dist(df, method = input$dmethod)
    })

    clusterplot <- reactive({
      plot(hclust(d(), method = input$cmethod))
    })

    model <- reactive({
      train(input$yvar ~ input$xvar, crimes,
            method = "lm",
            trControl = trainControl(
              method = "cv", number = 10,
              verboseIter = TRUE))
    })

    #render a barplot
    output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(crimes, aes_string(x = input$x,
                                        y = input$y)) + 
        geom_point(size = 3) + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
              axis.text.y = element_blank())
    })

    output$boxplot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(selectData3(), aes(x = region, y = selectData3()[ ,input$y2])) + 
        geom_boxplot(aes(fill = region)) + ylab(input$y2)+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
              axis.text.y = element_blank())
    })

    output$summary <- renderPrint({
      dataset <- na.omit(mydata())
      summary(dataset)
    })

    output$cluster <- renderPlot({
      fviz_cluster(mycluster(),data = df)
    })

    output$tree <- renderPlot({
      clusterplot()
    })

    output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(df)
    })

    output$model <- renderText({
      model()
    })
    })
```

Comment: Looks like you are providing a formula to `train` - the `input` strings are character type and not symbols. Perhaps you could try `as.formula` to build the formula from those strings?

Comment: Thanks Ben, tried it but still no luck.  I'm using ``yvar <- as.formula(input$yvar)`` and passing that as the argument to train().

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific. Try: `as.formula(paste(input$yvar, "~", input$xvar))` instead of `input$yvar ~ input$xvar`

Comment: Thanks Ben!  The model is running now.  Of course I get another error in shiny that looks like this: Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
  104: cat
   97: transform
   96: func
   94: f
   93: Reduce
   84: do
   83: hybrid_chain
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$model
    1: runApp

Comment: What do you want to show in `output$model`? I think `model()` will return a `train` object. The error might be you are trying to pass a `list` to a render method? Maybe try `renderPrint` instead of `renderText`?

Comment: If you change to `renderPrint` then use `print(model())` instead of just `model()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Working now!  Thank you Ben.  Really appreciate the help.